# Connection string not found with ASP.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm trying to get my local SQL database connecting to my ASP.Net project and nothing I try is working.
The database is named cinemaDatabase and its using windows authentication.

In web.config I have

```
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=cinemaDatabase;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then in a cshtml page I have

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;

@{
    var db = Database.Open("myDatabase");
 }
```

I keep getting this error

> InvalidOperationException: Connection string "myDatabase" was not
>   found. OpenNamedConnection

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Edit - 
Got it working, had to make a normal SQL server instead of the local MSSQLLocalDB one and change the data source in web.config to that.

Then used this code on my page and it connects now.

```
@using WebMatrix.Data; 
@using System.Data.SqlClient; 

@{ 

    var connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-58NGNQP;Initial Catalog=webDev;Integrated Security=True";
    var providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
    var db = Database.OpenConnectionString(connectionString, providerName);
}
```

Comment: You are getting this error in production or local ?

Comment: Just in local  http://imgur.com/a/8Ef2b

Comment: Are you looking at the correct web.config file?

Comment: I think so, its just the one in the root folder, right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with your connection string. Unfortunately, I don't have a running example right this moment with an attached ***.mdf*** file, but I believe something like this will do the job for you, I grabbed this string from [MSDN's article on connection strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Couple of important facts here:

1. `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0` - This specifies the start-on-demand localdb instance to use. Note that the version, v11.0 in this string, varies from installation to installation, and you should find the correct version for your string. (You should be able to find it easier below)
2. `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFilename.mdf` - this tells LocalDb to load that database file. Alternatively, localdb persists database files in your user home directory, or AppData directory somewhere.
3. `Integrated Security=true` - A connection string needs an authentication scheme. Two possible options are Integrated Security, which uses your windows credentials to attempt access to your database, which works well with many things, LocalDb being one of them. Another option is to use sql authentication and a sql name and password to connect.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I made a normal SQL database and now the same code in web.config works.